# built a Debian live USB

Tags: usb, debian, iso-image

I'm trying to create debian live USB, in order to migrate from Ubuntu to Debian (I want ot try it before).

I downloaded the iso 
http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-7.2-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso
taken from the list
http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/

After that, I inserted my USB pendrive (previously formatted in FAT), and by typing mount I found that the USB is /dev/sdb1.
Following the Debian site, I typed
dd if=debian-live-7.2-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4M

and what I obtained is
dd: opening `/dev/sdb1': Permission denied

I tried with sudo ..., and it work, but if I try to boot from the USB what I obtain is a black screen, followed by the normal booting of my laptop.

I checked the filesysytem of the USB with gparted, and it is not recognized.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After having made sure that the stick is unmounted:

As root :

```
cp debian.iso /dev/sdX
sync
```

see : http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html.en

So in your case it must be `sdb` and not sdb1